# Has рекомендовать something to do with "recommend"?

Tags: этимология, социолингвистика

In a social context, рекомендовать means to introduce people to somebody. At first I thought is was a complete false-friend, however now I see that they might not be that far apart. For instance, if you were introducing a commercial product, you probably would say:

> *I recommend/advise you read* **X** *book*.

So, when you say рекомендовать, is this a biased introduction of somebody? Like

> I recommend you this person, I know who this person is and it will be beneficial to you.

and not just introducing the person?

Comment: I think that "рекомендовать" is like "strongly suggest", and it can be not biased at all (depending on the context).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a definition of the word **Рекомендовать** from Словарь иностранных слов. As you can see, unbiased recommendation (3.) is now marked as outdated. Modern meaning is "I recommend you X, because he/she/it is useful/beneficial to you:

> РЕКОМЕНДОВА́ТЬ, ду́ю, ду́ет, несов. и сов. [польск. rekomendować < ср.-лат. recommendare < лат. mandāre поручать].
>   1. кого-что.Давать (дать) благоприятный отзыв о ком-чем-н., предлагать (предложить) использовать, принять куда-н. и т. п.Р. опытного работника. Р. кого-н. на должность заведующего.
>   2. что и с инфин.Советовать.Врачи не рекомендуют мне отдыхать на юге.
>   3. кого (что), устар.Знакомя с кем-н., называть (назвать), представлять (представить).Рекомендую вам мое семейство: жена, дочь.

Several ethymologic dictionaries claim that the word is borrowed around 1705 from Polish language ([rekomendować](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/46508)). However Словарь Ушакова marks this word as [borrowed from French language](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1008398#%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC0).

Comment: "Отрекомндоваться" meaning "to introduce oneself" is a bit less outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендовать always means to advise in modern Russian. So it cannot be used as unmarked "to introduce".